# Socrata - Pagination with $select

Tags: socrata

I'm using `$query=` for advance querying, however the results get paginated at 1000. Socrata is not taking the parameter `$limit=` when used with `$query=`.

What can I do to move to the next set of data?

Example:

```
https://<url>.json?$offset=1000&$limit=1000&$query=select distinct id

{
  "error" : true,
  "message" : "If $query is used, all options - [$limit, $offset] should not be specified in $query."
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should include your limit and offset within your `$query` like so:

`?$query=SELECT DISTINCT id LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 1000`

That should do the trick!